# How to auto mount a partition during initramfs/inird phase?

Tags: debian, encryption, boot-loader, luks, initramfs

I have an encrypted Debian linux system. I also try to detach the LUKS header from the encrypted container. The whole `/boot/` partition will be stored on a separate device. I thought I could place the LUKS header under `/boot/header/luks.img` , but during the initramfs/initrd phase this path doesn't exists because the `/boot/` partition isn't mounted yet.

So the question is how to automatically mount the `/boot/` partition before the system tries to open the encrypted device? Or is there any other (or better) way to make it work?

Comment: Does /etc/crypttab get it working right? I think there's a "load first or second" option that might help, but I'm not able to check/search now, if crypttab isn't too "late" already

Comment: It's a little bit complicated setup when you want to make it work the way I wanted to. I've managed to do it ultimately. See the answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this setup won't work OOTB because you have to mount some partition (in this case /boot/) in the initramfs/initrd phase, and by default there's no partition mounted there. Without the /boot/ partition you can't use the LUKS header. So the only way to make it work is to write some [custom scripts that will mount/unmount the partition in the initramfs/initrd phase](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2018/03/msg00121.html).

[I've manage to write some HowTo on this subject](https://gist.github.com/morfikov/0bd574817143d0239c5a0e1259613b7d), and the setup works really great.